# broadcastMessage in Twisted chat server

Tags: python, python-2.7, chat, twisted

I'm writing a chat server in Twisted and I have a problem in understanding **broacastMessage()** method:

```
def broadcastMessage(self, message):
    print list(self.factory.users.iteritems())

    for name, protocol in self.factory.users.iteritems():
        if protocol != self:
            protocol.sendLine(message)
```

I know *iteritems()* should yield a tuple, for example `('Roman', <__main__.ChatProtocol instance at 0x7fc80b8b67a0>)`. Now when iterating through this tuple `names` and `protocols` we are comparing that `protocol` if it's not a `self` instance, simply because we don't want to print a message for user who have sent it? *(Am i getting this right?)*

So expect it to work but it does not for some reason. Here's the *code*:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver

class ChatProtocol(LineReceiver):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory
        self.name = None
        self.state = "REGISTER"

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("What's your name?")

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if self.name in self.factory.users:
            del self.factory.users[self.name]
            self.broadcastMessage("%s has left the channel." % (self.name,))

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        if self.state == "REGISTER":
            self.handle_REGISTER(line)
        else:
            self.handle_CHAT(line)

    def handle_REGISTER(self, name):
        if name in self.factory.users:
            self.sendLine("Name taken, please choose another.")
            return
        self.sendLine("Welcome, %s!" % (name,))
        self.broadcastMessage("%s has joined the channel." % (name,))
        self.name = name
        self.factory.users[name] = self
        self.state = "CHAT"

    def handle_CHAT(self, message):
        message = "<%s> %s" % (self.name, message)
        self.broadcastMessage(message)

    def broadcastMessage(self, message):
        for name, protocol in self.factory.users.iteritems():
            if protocol != self:
                protocol.sendLine(message)

class ChatFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.users = {}

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return ChatProtocol(self)

reactor.listenTCP(8000, ChatFactory())
reactor.run()
```

And here's the *terminal session*:

```
(venv) metal@space ~/Documents/learning/twisted/chat_server $ telnet localhost 8000
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
What's your name?
Roman
Welcome, Roman!
```

**P.S.: I'm using *Telnet* to send messages.**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it doesn't work?  It looks like it works to me, both based on your terminal session transcript and local testing.

In your session transcript, you entered the name "Roman" and received the response "Welcome, Roman!".  This is due to the line:

```
self.sendLine("Welcome, %s!" % (name,))
```

A different connection to the same server receives the message "Roman has joined the channel." due to the line:

```
self.broadcastMessage("%s has joined the channel." % (name,))
```

Also, the `broadcastMessage` call could not send the "joined" message to the user who joined because at the point of its call, the "joined" user has not yet been added to the factory's `users` dict.